# How use method from other object /How pass right context?

Tags: php

```
class Person_Writer {
    function writeName (  ){
       echo $this ->name;
    }
    function writeAge ( ){
        echo $this ->age;
    }
}

class Person {
    function __construct($name,$age) {
        $this->writer = new Person_Writer;
        $this->name= $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    function __call($name, $arguments) {          
        $writter = $this->writer;
        call_user_func(array($this->writer, 'WriteName'));
        //  call_user_func(array(new Person_Writer, 'WriteName'));
    }
} 

$obj = new Person('sasha',28);        
$obj->writeName();
```

Error : 
**Notice: Undefined property: Person_Writer::$name in**

How use method from other object / How pass right context ?
I want to use  function writeName (  ) in $obj .

Comment: Try fixing the typo $writter = $this->writer;

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do there, this would work if you want to call a function of another object:

```
class Person_Writer {
    function writeName ($name){
        echo $name;
    }
    function writeAge ($age){
        echo $age;
    }
}

class Person{
    function __construct($name,$age) {
        $this->writer = new Person_Writer;
        $this->name= $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    function __call($name, $arguments) {
        $writer = $this->writer;
        $writer->writeName($this->name);
    }
} 

$obj = new Person('sasha',28);
$obj->writeName();
```

Why are you using **$this->name** in your **Persone_Writer** object ? This object won't know variables of the **Person** object that's why you got the undefined error.

**EDIT:** An other solution would be Hexana one where you extend objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are not extending the base class and you have a typo.  You are also not calling the writeAge() method.  Below works for me:

```
class Person_Writer {
public function writeName (  ){
    echo $this ->name;
}
function writeAge ( ){
    echo $this ->age;
}
}

class Person extends Person_Writer{
    function __construct($name,$age) {
        $this->writer = new Person_Writer;
        $this->name= $name;
        $this->age = $age;
    }
    function __call($name, $arguments) {

        $writer = $this->writer;

       call_user_func(array($this->writer, 'WriteName'));
      //  call_user_func(array(new Person_Writer, 'WriteName'));
    }
} 

$obj = new Person('sasha',28);

$obj->writeName();
echo '<br>';
$obj->writeAge();
```

Comment: Ok judging by the downvote, I must remember in future to not offer any help with typos etc

Comment: You already notice that in a comment, which was good and enough. When providing an answer the person who's asking except a reponse that fix is issue.

Comment: Updated my answer, so hopefully this works for the OP

Comment: I wanted to without inheritance but thank ou for yor help  +1